# WPF DataGrid Autogenerate Column Order

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a WPF datagrid with autogeneratecolumns = true.
It is bound to a list of POCO
Is there anyway I can set the column order by maybe setting some XML documentation on the properties in the class?

Obviously I can set autogenerate to false, and hard code the columns, but I'm wondering is there some other way of decorating my class/properties to take care of this.

Answer (score 3):

Not the nicest method, but works for me:

In the "AutoGeneratedColumns" event, you can set your columns DisplayIndex for each column by its header.

```
private void datagrid1_AutoGeneratedColumns(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        datagrid1_.Columns.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Header.ToString() == "header").DisplayIndex = 0;
    }
```

Take care of exceptions, etc...

Or I think the order of properties in the declaration of the class forecasts the autogenerated column order.